# Bootstrap JS and Navbar Button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I normally use Ruby on rails to develop my work with sublime text as my text editor, but today I am using just using notepad and creating a site locally. Now normally all my js and css is rendered perfectly via the asset pipeline in rails but I am having trouble getting the js to work, in particular the dropdown button in the navbar.

i am calling Jquery within the header

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I am calling my bootstrap.js file

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The css for the navbar is as follows

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">

  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>


  <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Am i missing something blindly obvious because the button is not responding?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Ruby on rails is a text editor too?!

Comment: edited question @tkone, constructive answers would be great!

Comment: Well...see your question still don't make sense so it's hard to be constructive.  The code you're showing is HTML, not CSS.  There is no "button" in the code, rather a link which has a CSS class which makes it appear to be a button.  Have you tried using the debugger in your browser to ensure that the `onclick` method for the link is being called when you click on it?

Comment: The css is provided by bootstrap.css. what is this doing <a class="btn btn-navbar"? I was under the impression that this was the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN wasnt pulling the jquery so i have hosted the file locally now and it works fine

Answer (score 7):

Have you included the required bootstrap.css stylesheet?

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Edit 1:**

Here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uwoxan/1/edit) with your HTML/bootstrap. If you aren't seeing the same output then something is indeed wrong. If you're expecting some behavior when one of the navbar buttons gets clicked, then it isn't actually an error: there is no js behavior attached to the click of the navbar.

Bootstrap will provide you with a "prettified" navbar, it changes the aesthetics but not the behavior, you still need to connect to the individual clicks and define your own behavior for them.

**Edit 2:**

To connect to the clicks you have to get your menu items and use jQuery to define onclick behaviors. An example would be to define unique ids for each navbar item

```
<li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="about" href="#">About Us</a></li>
```

And then retrieve them with jQuery's selectors and attach click handlers:

```
$("#home").click(function() {
  alert('home clicked');
});

$("#about").click(function() {
  alert('about clicked');
});
```

I've edited the jsbin to add this example.

Comment: Yes definitely behaving different, when i click my button nothing happens

Comment: Can you provide a jsBin example or edit your question to include the javascript you're using to handle the clicks?

Comment: got it solved now, the CDN wasnt pulling the jquery so i have hosted the file locally now and it works fine... thank you for your help though, much appreciated